# MySQL: Defining columns in SELECT statement with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I want to specify which columns to select using a subquery; is this possible in MySQL?  For example, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  table1_id INT,
  number VARCHAR,
  color VARCHAR,
  shape VARCHAR,
  .
  .
  .
  PRIMARY KEY (table1_id)
);
INSERT INTO table1 ('1', '25', 'purple', 'circle');
INSERT INTO table1 ('2', '30', 'orange', 'triangle');
INSERT INTO table1 ('3', '82', 'blue', 'square');

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  name VARCHAR,
  display BOOL,
  flag2 BOOL,
  .
  .
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
INSERT INTO table2 ('number', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO table2 ('color', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO table2 ('shape', '1', '1');
```

Each 'name' in table2 is one of the column names ('par1', 'par2', etc) in table1.  These are not all combined due to how the data is created and entered into the database.
I want to do a select statement (which will then be used to create a view), where I return only the columns in table1 defined by flags in table2.  So, I want to do something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE (flag1="1" && flag2="0")) FROM table1;
```

EDIT:
It seems like something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
WHERE t2.name IN(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='table1') 
AND t2.display="1";
```

If I list the individual column names instead of the subquery it does work, but I can't get mysql to return the column names in the correct format.

With the example data I added above, I want to select each column from table1 which has an entry in table2 with display=true.  So, it should return 'color' and 'shape' data for each entry in table1.

EDIT 2:
The above does not work, since it still selects all columns from table1 regardless of the criteria in table2.  I suspect this is not possible in mysql, since according to everything I have been able to find you can't use a subquery to select which columns to return.

Given the above example, the return I want is:

```
+-------------------+
| color  | shape    |
+-------------------+
| purple |   circle |
| orange | triangle |
|   blue |   square |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: A select statement cannot have a dynamic structure of the result set. The list of columns of the statement must be fix. You cannot do what you do what you wand in SQL. You will have to dynamically build the statement.

Comment: It seems like something like this should work:

    SELECT * FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
    WHERE t2.name IN(
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' 
        AND TABLE_NAME='table1') 
    AND t2.flag1="1";

If I list the individual column names instead of the subquery it does work, but I can't get mysql to return the column names in the correct format.

Comment: How do the names appear in `table2.name`? Can you show examples?

Comment: see edit above: I added some example data to show what I mean.

Comment: Does your code really work, e. g. `INSERT INTO table1 (1, 25, purple, circle)` without quotes around "purple" and "circle"?

Comment: I made up this example as I typed; my actual tables are very long and not conducive to easily providing an example.  If I were actually running this then yes, I would need extra quotes.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Do you have any experience with SQL? My impression is not. Please try to study more on the subject before you continue. I have made a SQLFiddle demo for you so you could play around.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25958/2

Comment: I created an SQLFiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/150d9/3 of the code you posted last - edited so that it runs. What is different in the result that it shows from what you want to have?

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with sql, but I have spent time looking through documentation to try to solve this issue.  I edited my original post; the example I put doesn't actually do what I want since the it still returns all the columns in table1.

Comment: Oke, lets try something different. Provide the desired result in a table style format.

Comment: @user3175280 Something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25958/8

Comment: Yes, obviously that works, but I want to select all columns in table1 that have display="1" in table2, without knowing ahead of time which columns those are.  So, I can't just use SELECT color, shape because there might also be 10 other columns that have display="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SET @sql = (

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM
      (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1') a
     JOIN table2
     ON table2.name = a.column_name
     WHERE table2.display = "1"
    ); 

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM table1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/150d9/135)

Comment: Thank you!  That does work for my example, and I think with some modification will work with my actual database.